# Android - Samsung 'Themes' - How to design/use my own Theme (for personal use)?

Tags: android, themes, android-theme, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

In recent years, Samsung smartphones have included a Themes app.
There are plenty of Designers who publish Themes on there, for use on newer Samsung phones.
(Some are *Free*, others *aren't*)..

However, I would like to design **my own** Theme, purely for **personal** use.
In other words, I *do not* need it to go on the official Themes app.
(Again, purely for personal use).

**Is there an Application (for PC), which I can use to Design my own Themes, such as these?**
Any information about this topic is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER:**
What I was after is called "Samsung Mobile Theme Editor".
More information can be found [here this link](https://developer.samsung.com/theme), which is the official Samsung page for it.